# Resizing a Symbol's Width

Tags: sketch-app, resize, symbols, scale

Is there a way to resize a symbol's width without resizing the height of the symbol also?

I just want to change the width of my symbol.

See below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have your width/height locked as I don't have the similar problem when I unlock it.

You can find the lock icon on the right hand, it looks like this:

[image]

Unlock it and you should not have this problem anymore.

Comment: Didn't spot that I had it locked. Thanks!! :)